# How to access stylesheet when I render as EJS in a dynamic route based on URL parameters

Tags: express, url-parameters, routeparams, route-parameters

I recently started learning Express.js and mongoose by creating a simple To-Do List, and now I'm stuck with a basic thing.

When I tried to render a EJS file in a dynamic route based on URL parameters, I was unable to apply the `stylesheet.css` which is stored in the `public` folder for the EJS, and the following error message showed up in the browser console.
The error message:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/mylist/css/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

And of course, the URL request was `http://localhost:3000/mylist/css/styles.css`.

On the other hand, the same EJS file rendered in the home route was able to access the `stylesheet.css`. And the request URL was `http://localhost:3000/css/styles.css`.

So I guess whatever I try to render, the request URL has to be `http://localhost:3000/css/styles.css` in my file structure. However, I don't know how to get rid of `mylist` from `http://localhost:3000/mylist/css/styles.css`, when I render as EJS in a dynamic route based on URL parameters.

What's wrong with my code?　How do you solve it?

File structure:

[image]

app.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static("/public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

const itemsSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String });
const customListsSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String, items: [itemsSchema] });

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);
const CustomList = mongoose.model("CustomList", customListsSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res) =>  {
  Item.find((err, foundItems) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems });
    }
  });
});

app.get("/mylist/:customListName", (req, res) => {
  const customListName = req.params.customListName;
  CustomList.findOne({ name: customListName }, (err, foundCustomList) => {
    if (!err) {
      if (foundCustomList) {
        res.render("list", {
          listTitle: foundCustomList.name,
          newListItems: foundCustomList.items
        });
      } else {
        const customList = new CustomList({ name: customListNamem });
        customList.save((err) => {
          if (!err) {
            res.redirect("/mylist/" + customListName);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

list.ejs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>To-Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box" id="heading">
    <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box">

    <form action="/delete" method="post">
      <% newListItems.forEach((newListItem) => { %>
        <div class="item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= newListItem._id %>" onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <p><%= newListItem.name %></p>
        </div>
      <% }); %>
    </form>

    <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
      <button type="submit" name="listName" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried and replaced `app.use(express.static("/public"));` with `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to fix the bug by myself.

It was caused by the fact that the path to the stylesheet in the EJS was a relative path. It seems that it has to be an absolute path.

So I simply added a forward slash `/` and turned `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">` in the `list.ejs`.

Now it works with `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));` in `app.js`, however it doesn't still work with `app.use(express.static("/public"));`.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

I couple `__dirname` with `path.join()` to create an absolute path to the directory, that will work on the machine it is being run on.

What you're doing with:
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` setting the static folder to `/Absolute/Path/To/Repo/public/` where the `__dirname` is the "/Absolute/Path/To/Repo/" part.

So run on my computer it would return:
`/home/proto/UWebDev/Playground/myapp/public`
and on your it would be whatever the path to that particular `public` directory would be.

Conversely, in your initial code you simply used:

`app.use(express.static("/public")` ; which if console logged anywhere will return `/public`. Which is an absolute path that I'm assuming isn't in you repo since,I haven't heard of anyone making a repo out of there machine's root directory.

For what it's worth, what you've done in `app.js`  made it so anything on the front-end that begins with `/` is *actually* referencing `/ABS/PATH/TO/REPO/public/`; in this particular scenario, I believe simply replacing your original `"/public"` with `"./public"` would have worked as well (in addition adding the `/` to the path to the css as you did.

Sidenote: `path.join(__dirname,'public)` === `path.join(__dirname,'/public')` for what it's worth.

I'm fairly new to developing, so if anyone sees something I made a mistake on or oversimplified, please point it out, but hopefully this helps someone who get to this page looking for answers.